# i am using this for add .php ext in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following to add `.php` extension in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

For example if the URL is `www.doamin.com/create` than it will call `create.php`.

This is working fine, but when I want to call `create_new`, then it goes wrong. Page give error.

Can somebody help me so both conditions can run simple create and create_add?

Comment: I know this is a **rewrite** question, but why not use `MultiViews`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `_` to your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_]+)$ $1.php
```

Comment: hi sir there is another problem. i paste my htaccess file in root folder. and when i call the www.doamin.com/notes/create. its get error. and if i paste htaccess file in notes folder its run fine. can you tell me why me file not supported in root

Answer (score 0):

Use http://regexpal.com/ to check your regular expressions.

`[a-z]` will catch only symbols from a to z. Add `-` and `_` and numbers (`0-9`) to catch everything.

So use this regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-_.a-z0-9]+)$ $1.php [L]
```